# Прочитать значение массива C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli

```
DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;
HKEY hKey = 0;
String^ value;
DWORD value_length = 1024;
RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("Software\\Valve\\Steam"), &hKey);
RegQueryValueEx(hKey, _T("Language"), NULL, &dwType, (LPBYTE)&value, &value_length);
```

Добрый день, вопрос такой, почему данный код не срабатывает и выбивает ошибку? Прошу помочь. Если что, нужно вернуть значение `String^`

Comment: Сразу после компиляции - ошибка

Comment: Вы пытаетесь ссылку на `System::String` закастить в указатель на байт. Понятно, что это не будет работать.

Comment: Вопрос не в том, что нужно вернуть, а в том, что нужно передавать в `RegQueryValueEx`. Если вы ответите себе на этот вопрос, проблема станет более понятной.

Comment: Можно тогда пример рабочий? мне надо от сюда Software\Valve\Steam вытащить параметр Language ( он там english, russian и тд)

Comment: Ну, не ленитесь сами разобраться. Что нужно, согласно документации, передавать 5-ым параметром в `RegQueryValueEx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного подправил ваше решение. Пробуйте так

```
    DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;
    HKEY hKey = 0;
    String^ value;
    DWORD bufSize = 1024;
    LPVOID buf = new char[bufSize];
    RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Valve\\Steam", &hKey);
    RegQueryValueEx(hKey, L"Language", NULL, &dwType, (BYTE*)buf, &bufSize);
    WCHAR *wch = reinterpret_cast<WCHAR *>(buf);
    value = gcnew String(wch);
```

Comment: Беда в том, что я даже не могу понять что за ошибка. http://rgho.st/8W52Mr84c/image.png

Comment: @Corle добавьте `#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32")`